# WPGraphQL and Elementor getting page or post css and scripts

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, elementor, wp-graphql

Elementor is generating page specific styling and scripts inside head section of the WordPress page. Is there a way to read them to GraphQL?

Answer (score 0):

I did the same for WpBakery pagebuilder in 2 steps:

1. register new field in graphQL with my CSS from editor, something like:

   ```
    add_action( 'graphql_register_types', function() {
              register_graphql_field( 'Page', 'customCSS', [
                 'type' => 'String',
                 'description' => __( 'Custom CSS from Editor', 'wp-graphql' ),
                 'resolve' => function() {
                // call your function which return your custom css
                return $this->addPageCustomCssToGraphql();
                 }
              ] );
            } );
   ```
2. request them in Gatsby page and using Helmet plugin show your CSS in HEAD of your page.